# Как назначить свой конструктор конструктором по умолчанию?

Tags: java, конструктор

Есть абстрактный класс `CalculationAbstract` и несколько его наследников. У этого класса есть два поля, значения для которых нужно взять из объекта главного класса приложения. Решил сделать это через конструктор

```
   public CalculationAbstract (GUI parent) {
    this.dataTable = parent.getDataTable();
    this.pointList = parent.getPointList();
}
```

В абстрактном классе ошибок нет, а вот в его наследниках произошла ошибка, что у `CalculationAbstract` нет конструктора по умолчанию.

> There is no dafault constructor available in CalculationAbstract

Я знаю почему эта ошибка возникает. Потому что при создании своего конструктора, конструктор по умолчанию не создается. Но мне и не нужен пустой конструктор. Есть ли способ назначить свой конструктор конструктором по умолчанию, чтобы исправить эту ошибку?

Класс одного из наследников

```
       public class ExpCalculate  extends CalculationAbstract{
// y = exp (b*x+a)
public double getNewX(){
    return CurrentPoint.getX();
}
public double getNewY(){
    return Math.log(CurrentPoint.getY());
}
public double getTransformedA(){
    return this.calculateCommonPart().get(0);
}

public double getTransformedB(){
    return this.calculateCommonPart().get(1);
}
public ArrayList<Double> getApproximationY(){


    ArrayList<Double> YList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (double i = getMaxX0(); i<getMaxX0(); i+=deltaX*0.01){
        //double Y = Math.exp(getTransformedB()* pointList.get(i).getX() + getTransformedA());
        double Y = Math.exp(getTransformedB()*i + getTransformedA());
        YList.add(Y);
    }
    return YList;
}
public String getFormula (){
    return "Y = e^" + getTransformedB() + "*x +" + getTransformedA();
    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите конструктор наследника, который генерит ошибку

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar Опубликовал класс одного из наследников, ошибка при объявлении класса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я знаю почему эта ошибка возникает.

Нет вы не совсем верно понимаете ситуацию.

Ваш класс наследник не имеет конструктора, следовательно компилятор создает для него конструктор по умолчанию - без параметров, который вызывает такой же конструктор в предке, а его нет.

Варианта 2:

1) Вы создаете конструктор по умолчанию (а он всегда без параметров) в родителе - но вы такой вариант не хотите

2) Вы создаете конструктор в наследнике и там явно указываете через `super()` вызов своего конструктора в предке, примерно так:

```
ExpCalculate(GUI parent) {
   super(parent);
}
```

Если ни один вариант не подходит, значит вы что-то неверно проектируете или (что не исключено) - я вас не понимаю.